# Angular - How to Show Hide div based on textinput and select dropdown

Tags: angular

In Angular-14 project, I am implementing show/div. I have two text inputs and one select dropdown.

The select drop down can either be Active (1) or inactive (0)

**What I want to achieve is that, If any of the two text Inputs gets typed or the selected dropdown on change has value, then I want a div to be shown and if there I press backspace and make the textbox empty or the select dropdown has no value, then it should be disappeared.**

I have tried below code.

component.ts:

```
  selectedName: string = '';
  selectedNo: string = '';
  selectedStatus: number = -1;

showDiv!:boolean;

  showDivData(textValue:any){
    this.selectedName = textValue;
    this.selectedNo = textValue;
    this.selectedStatus = textValue;
    if(this.selectedName.length > 0 || this.selectedNo.length > 0 || this.selectedStatus !== -1){
      this.showDiv = true;
    }
    else{
      this.showDiv = false;
    }
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
      this.showDiv=false;
    }
```

component.html:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-6 ">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="studentName">Student Name:</label>
        <input
        type="text"
        autocomplete="off"
        class="form-control"
        id="studentName"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedName"
        (keypress)="showDivData(selectedName)"
        placeholder="Student Name"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-6 ">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="studentNumber">Student No.:</label>
        <input
        type="text"
        autocomplete="off"
        class="form-control"
        id="studentNumber"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedNo"
        (keypress)="showDivData(selectedName)"
        placeholder="Student Number"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-6 ">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="student_status">Student Status</label>
        <ng-select [items]="statusStatusData"
          [selectOnTab]="true"
          [searchable]="true"
          bindValue="key"
          bindLabel="value"
          placeholder="Select Student Status"
          [multiple]="false"
          [(ngModel)]="selectedStatus"
          (change)="showDivData(selectedStatus)"
          [clearable]="true">
        </ng-select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div *ngIf="showDiv">Div Shown</div>
```

I got these two problems on the component.ts:

1. There is this error :

> This expression is not callable.   Type 'Boolean' has no call
> signatures.ngtsc(2349)

and showDiv is highlighted for both text inputs

2. When the select dropdown is onChange, nothing happens:

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your method is called `show_div`, but you try to call `showDiv(...)` in the *change* and *keypress* events. `showDiv` is your boolean field that defines the visibility of the "Div Shown" div, not the function that sets this boolean.

Comment: I have corrected that in my code as you said, but on KeyPress of the textinput and select drop down, the div is still hidden and also the search is bringing no result. Thanks